# Replace more than value in Azure Data Factory Data Flow

Tags: azure, etl, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory

I want to replace some values in one column using expression language in Data Factory Data Flow. I tried to combine multiple replace statements and if conditions in Derived Columns but it didn’t work.

For example:

```
case

when column = ’SA’ then ‘SB’

when column = ‘PA’ then ‘PO’

when column = ‘KL’ then ‘KLL’

when column = ‘AAB’ then ‘A’

when column = ‘WWE’ then ‘A’

else ‘n’

end
```

Does anybody know how to handle this? I am new with Data Factory and need some help please.

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your expression is wrong.

About how to build a correctly expressions, please reference:

1. [Mapping Data Flow Expression Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder).
2. [Data transformation expressions in Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions).

For example, replace my `ename` columne with 'zzz' using this expression in Visual Expression Builder:

```
case(ename=='aaa','zzz',ename)
```

[image]

Another test, add more conditions:
[image]

So your expression should like this:

```
case(column=='SA','SB',
     column=='PA','PO',
     column== 'KL','KLL',
     column== 'AAB','A',
     column== 'WWE','A',
     'n'
    )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it just me or is the documentation super confusing or it's just really hard to get into DataFactory? 
Example: The arguments for this function look like this `case(condition, true_expression, false_expression)`
How would I know that I could do something like the solution?

Answer (score -4):

This should work

```
case(fname=='SA','SB', fname=='PA','PO',fname=='KL','KLL', fname=='AAB','A',fname=='WWE','A','n' )
```